# Event Handlers Might Not Be Not Raised in a Default Document in IIS 7 or IIS 7.5 Integrated Mode?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, iis-7.5

After pulling my hair out for the last three days in my first non-upgraded ASP.NET 4.0 Web Application, I stumble across this post explaining it all.

http://jai-on-asp.blogspot.com/2010/06/changes-and-differences-between-aspnet.html under the section labeled: **Event Handlers Might Not Be Not Raised in a Default Document in IIS 7 or IIS 7.5 Integrated Mode**

Apparently, an asp.net page at this address: http://www.mydomain.com/  will not post back to itself without explicitly adding action="default.aspx" in the `<form`> tag.

Well, what happens when you are using a Master Page (where the `<form`> tag is location when using Master Pages)?

How do I get my default.aspx pages to postback to themselves in .NET 4.0 using Master Pages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whether the form is specified on the *default page*, or in the *master page*, it is still accessible via the Form *property* on the page.

Therefore, you should be able to set it's action in the code behind for that page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Form.Action = "Default.aspx";
}
```

Comment: True, and that was more of a brain-fart on the masterpage side-note issue. The bigger issue is just the inconsistency that I have to remember every time I'm using a default page that I have explicitly set the action which I don't have to for any other page.  I don't get it.  Why the change?