# Button Event Handler Not Firing on Homepage Without /default.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm at a loss over here. On the root of my application (default.aspx), I have a basic ASP.NET Button control on the page with an event handler wired up via its onClick event.

Since it's the root, hitting either / or default.aspx will bring you to this page. When clicking the button, the event handler is only getting called if the FilePath is in the url (default.aspx).

To be more clear:

whatever.com/default.aspx <------ The event handler gets called when the button is clicked

whatever.com <------ event handler is not getting called when button is clicked.

I should note, this page doesn't have much on it.  No jquery files included, no javascript, nothing besides a DropDownList and this Button. The Web.Config doesn't have much in it either, at least nothing I can see that would have any impact on this.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSelection" OnClick="btnSelection_OnClick" runat="server" Text="Submit" />

protected void btnSelection_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new Exception("Test"); // Only reaches here if /default.aspx is in the url
}
```

This is probably something small I'm missing.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link:
[Event Handlers Might Not Be Not Raised in a Default Document in IIS 7 or IIS 7.5 Integrated Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673291/event-handlers-might-not-be-not-raised-in-a-default-document-in-iis-7-or-iis-7-5)

If nothing, it should point you in the right direction.