# Upgraded ASP.NET Website to Web Application events not firing on default.aspx when accessed from '/'

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Similar to this question:

[Button Event Handler Not Firing on Homepage Without /default.aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448144/button-event-handler-not-firing-on-homepage-without-default-aspx)

But the accepted answer didn't help.

I recently upgraded an asp.net website to a web application following the guidelines here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx

Everything was going fine until I added a button to default.aspx with it's own click event.

I've got this button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDoStuff" runat="server" Text="Do Something" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btn_Click"/>
```

bound to an event in the code-behind:

```
    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
```

and I double checked the designer.cs has the button:

```
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btnDoStuff;
```

I've tried this on default.aspx itself, and putting it into a custom control. Both ways the event doesn't fire unless I navigate to localhost/default.aspx explicitly.

I'm more of an MVC guy, so I could really use some help on this. How do I get custom events to fire without explicitly navigating to default.aspx?

It's worth noting the other events Page_Load and Page_PreInit work fine.

**Update**

I've now tried manually adding the event to the button in the Page_Load event. Clicking the button appears to just reload the page, but the bound event is never fired.

Comment: Have you tried manually adding the event handler in `Page_Load`?  I've found that sometimes can help to ensure events are handled.

Comment: Just tried it - didn't work, thanks for the suggestion though!