# Default page is not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

In my project `Index.aspx` page is set as a default document.
I tried to debug is not firing the button click event on `localhost:1992`,but  it is working perfectly on `localhost:1992/Index.aspx`.

ISSUE : project working in `localhost:1992/Index.aspx` not working `localhost:1992`

Kindly give the solution for this issue?

**UPDATE**

I've set `Index.aspx` page as the startup page

**NOTE : Client side click is working. only server side click is the problem here.**

Comment: SUCCESS  link : [Click Here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673291/event-handlers-might-not-be-not-raised-in-a-default-document-in-iis-7-or-iis-7-5) This link is working for me..

Answer (score 3):

Because you haven't specified a page as a **startup** page.

Right click on the page you want to be the start page and then click on the *set as a start up page* option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by editing web.config file,

```
<system.webServer>
 <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />               
            <add value="index.aspx"/>
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

**Use clear tag before add tag**

Comment: This is my code

  <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="Index.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
Alraedy done...

Comment: try restart visual studio and after clearing browsing cache

Comment: I was tried with clearing browser cache..i will check with restart visual studio..if have any changes let you know.